# Is it possible to switch on/off the extension from the popup without the chrome://extensions tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm about to finish my extension and all I need is an on/off switch in my popup.html that will control the same switch in the 'chrome://extensions' tab. Is it possible?

This is what I've done: 
popup.html:

```
// on/off switch
<div class="center custom-control custom-switch">
   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
   <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">PAUSE / START</label>
</div>
```

popup.js:

```
var ss = document.getElementById("customSwitch1");

$(ss).click(function() {
  if($(ss).prop("checked")){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({isOn: "true"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response.farewell);
    });
  }
  else{
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({isOn: "false"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response.state);
    });
  }
});
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.isOn == "true")
      sendResponse({state: "true"});
    if (request.isOn == "false")
      sendResponse({state: "false"});
});
```

[This is what I want to control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFosW.png)

Comment: You could try to disable it programmatically using [chrome.management.setEnabled](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-setEnabled), but I doubt you can enable it once it is disabled, because once disabled, no code from the extension is run.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko You're totally right, if I disabled it I can't renable it cause it won't be shown anymore, my bad.

Comment: You can write a separate extension to toggle the main one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the extension enabled in chrome and let your popup control the pause/start of what your extension is working on only and not disabling the whole extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can, potentially, disable your own extension from code. In fact, you can even uninstall it.

See [`chrome.management` API](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/management) on how to do it.

However, that would leave you with no ability to enable it back.

1. If you're trying to control another extension, it's a valid approach.
   You'd need the `"management"` permission to affect other extensions.
2. If you're trying to control own behavior, you'll need to implement that in the extension logic.

   ```
   /* Pseudocode */
   function someEventHandler() {
     if (state.enabled) {
       // Do stuff
     } else {
       console.log("Functionality disabled, ignoring SomeEvent");
     }
   }
   ```

   Note that to persist this setting, you'd probably want to save it somewhere that survives extension restart; [`chrome.storage` API](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/storage) is probably your best choice.